# What is the motivation to explicitly set the "falign-functions" compiler flag to a certain value?

Tags: c, gcc, embedded, cross-compiling

I am working on the SW for an embedded system and trying to understand some low-level details that was setup by an earlier developer. The target platform is a custom made [OpenRISC 1200](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenRISC_1200) processor, synthesized in a FPGA. The software is built using a GCC based cross-compiler.

Among the compiler flags I find this one: `-falign-functions=16`. There is a comment in the build configuration saying:

> On Open RISC 1200, function alignment needs to be on a cache boundary (16 bytes). If not, performance suffer severely.

I realize my understanding of cache memories are a bit shallow and I should probably read something like: [What Every Programmer Should Know About Memory](https://www.akkadia.org/drepper/cpumemory.pdf). I haven't yet, but I will. With that said, I have some questions:

1. I understand that this is about minimizing cache misses in the instruction cache, but why is that achieved by setting the function alignment to the instruction cache line size (i.e. 16 bytes)?
2. If this is the most memory efficient way, wouldn't you expect this to be the default setting for function alignment in the cross-compiler? I mean, for a more common platform like x86, amd64 or ARM you don't need to care about function alignments (or am I wrong?).

Comment: Aligning functions or data means losing memory as you get holes in your memory. Basically for each function you could lose up to 15 bytes (or something like this). Might be very important on some MCUs.

Comment: If your function is aligned on a cache line, it means you fill an entire cache line at the first miss. Whether performance really suffers is hard to say, the easiest is to just give it a try.

Comment: Also performance drop will depend on the kind of system (single or multicore) and software (multithreaded or not)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most architectures have aspects of memory access and instructions that can depend on alignment.

> but why is that achieved by setting the function alignment to the instruction cache line size

The CPU will fetch complete cache lines from memory (as if the memory is divided into these larger blocks rather than bytes). So if all the data you need fits in one cache line, there is just one fetch, but if you have even just 2 bytes of data, but one byte is the end of a cache line and the other byte the start of the next, well now it has to load in two complete cache lines. This wastes space in the small CPU cache, and more memory transfers.

A [quick search](https://opencores.org/projects/or1k_old/openrisc%201200) indicates that the OpenRISC 1200 uses a 16 byte cache line, so when targeting that specifically, aligning the start of any data you have on those 16 byte multiples helps avoid straddling two lines within one function / piece of data.

> If this is the most memory efficient way, wouldn't you expect this to be the default setting for function alignment in the cross-compiler?

There can be more to it than that. Firstly, this alignment is achieved by wasting "padding" memory. If you would have used 1 byte of a cache line calling a function, then another 15 bytes are wasted to reach the 16 byte boundary.

Also in the case of a function call, there is a reasonable chance that memory will be in cache anyway, and jumping forward might leave the cached memory, causing a load that would otherwise not be needed.

So this leaves a trade off, functions that use little stack space and return quickly, might not benefit much from the extra alignment, but a function that runs for longer and uses more stack space might benefit by not "wasting" cache space on the "previous function".

---

Another reason alignment is often desired is when dealing with instructions that either require it outright (fail on an unaligned address), or are much slower (with loads/stores getting split up into parts), or maybe some other effects (like a load/store not being atomic if not properly aligned).

With a quick search I believe the general alignment requirement on OR1200 appears to be 4 bytes, even for 8 byte types. So in this respect an alignment of at least 4 would seem desirable, and 8 or 16 might only provide a benefit in certain cases mentioned before.

I am not familiar with Open RISC specifically, but on some platforms instructions added at a later date (e.g. 16byte / 128bit SSE instructions) require or benefit from an alignment greater than what was the default (I believe AMD64 upped the default alignment to 16, but then later AVX came wanting 32 byte alignment).

Comment: So whether the function alignment is effective or not depends on the benchmarking tests: If I test and measure with small functions there is little or even negative impact on performance. If I test and measure larger functions there will probably be a performace boost. Then I need to estimate some kind of "nominal" function behaviour of the real program and decide if the function alignment is suitable for that. Right?

Comment: Well you could recompile some existing programs, if "15 bytes wasted" etc. matters or not is like if your algorithm could fit in cache in theory, but now doesn't so hits memory on every iteration and the memory is too slow. The SSE/AVX alignment thing I have had real problems with before, but I couldn't quickly find any OpenRISC instruction that has such a requirement. I suppose on that side your "custom made" chip might not follow the same rules as I found searching?

Comment: The OpenRISC is most certainly the same as you found in your search results. With "custom made" I only meant it has various perihperals, e.g. bus controllers, watchdog, etc, connected.